# Weird error when trying to add a stored procedure to PVCS

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pvcs

I'm trying to add an SQL stored procedure to our PVCS directory, and I'm seeing a weird error pop up.  First, I get a dialog box containing `ÿþC`.  When I click OK on this dialog box, I'm told that -

> An error has ocurred: The stored
>   procedure code does not use the CREATE
>   method.  Please check your syntax.

Despite the fact that my procedure code DOES use the `CREATE` method.  I have also debugged my create procedure statement in the SQL Server Management Studio.

What is going on?

Answer (score 3):

I was using a non-standard character encoding in Notepad++ (UCS-2 Little Endian).  PVCS (Merant Version Manager) can't handle non-standard encodings.  When I switched to ANSI encoding, the error went away.